# Google Maps Web Serivce API for finding cities based on coordinates (server side)

Tags: google-maps, lucene

Which is the exact Google Maps API, which I can use to send my geocoordinates to, and get teh closest larger location (think, village, town, city, region, etc)?

I need it also to be in proper international naming, because i am building a search engine, and I spotted that many locations remain unsearcheable unless they are typed with the exact specific characters used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Reverse Geocoding". You can use this via the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).